# Table A except Table B (relating more than one column)

Tags: sql

I successfully query this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
WHERE NOT (column1 IN 
(SELECT column1 FROM tableB) AND columnDate='9999-12-31');
```

Where `tableA` has around 35000k (35million) records and `tableB` has 5k (5 thousand).
I retrieve all records from `tableA` except `tableB` in less than 5 minutes.

The problem is when I try (for another example with the same records volume) to achieve the same result using 3 columns (keys):

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
WHERE NOT (column1 || column2 || column3 IN 
(SELECT column1 || column2 || column3 FROM tableB) AND columnDate='9999-12-31');
```

I retrieve all records from `tableA` except `tableB` in 1 hour and 40 minutes....!

Can I query it more efficiently?

Comment: Is it a one-time query? Can you create an index on `column1 || column2 || column3` on tableB?

Comment: I created an index for the three columns (A, B, C). There is no difference in the results. Then I tried to create an index using pipes but retrieved syntax error...

Comment: No, creating separate indexes on a, b, and c won't cut it. You need to create a function-based index on а || b || c. Try `CREATE INDEX idx ON tableA (a || b || c);`

Comment: I assume the poster isn't really interested in a || b || c, but whether (a, b, c) is in the second table.

Comment: Podiluska, I am querying on a greenplum database

Comment: The syntax is: CREATE INDEX tableB_idx ON tableB
USING BTREE (column1, column2, column3);

Comment: if you have `('a', 'bc', 'd')` in table A and `('ab', 'c', 'd')` in table B would you expect the row to appear?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM tableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT null FROM tableB where a.column1=column1 and a.column2=column2 and a.column3=column3)
AND columnDate<>'9999-12-31'
```

Comment: This plus an index on tableB(column1, column2, column3)

Comment: There is something lacking: my original 1h40m query returns 63.465.598 records (correct). This one returns 22.280.920

Comment: @user1788913 as you can see, both queries returns the same result, your query is returning a different result. I suspect we have not been given the correct information in the question. Are you sure your strange column columndate is where it is suppose to be ?

Comment: @user1788913 maybe you are not looking for the combination of the 3 columns, try replacing the 2 'and' with 'or' inside the subselect

Answer (score 0):

One way is a filtering left join:

```
select  * 
from    tableA a
left join
        tableB b
on      b.col1 = a.col1
        and b.col2 = a.col2
        and b.col3 = a.col3
where   a.columnDate <> '9999-12-31'
        and b.id is null -- No match found in B
```

Comment: The id column in tableB stands for what?

Comment: The primary key in tableB (or any other column that is not nullable.)

Comment: There is something lacking: my original 1h40m query returns 63.465.598 records (correct). This one returns 22.280.920