# Get all rows not matching with another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like, concatenation

I've a tricky question. I have a table with numbers:

- 37823782
- 37823782
- 37823782
- 38478934
- 90003922

And another table with prefixes:

- 378
- 3847
- 384
- 001

I want to find all numbers matching the longest prefix. I succeded with this code:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT numbers FROM table1 GROUP BY numbers") or die ("Query error code 1"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    $numbers =$row["numbers"];

    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE '".$numbers."' LIKE CONCAT(prefix, '%') ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(prefix) DESC LIMIT 1");
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {

        // That's it

    }       

}
```

Now what i want to simply make the opposite thing. I want to find all numbers not matching any prefix. In short in the above example i made i should get "90003922". I thought to use **NOT LIKE CONCAT (prefix, '%')** but it's not working. Any idea?

Comment: `...WHERE GROUP BY...` is incorrect SQL.

Comment: What about this sequence of prefixes 378 **3847** 384 001 **5647**? Which is longest?

Comment: look at this!<br>
this will help you!<br>
[exept table][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160913/table-a-except-table-b-relating-more-than-one-column

Comment: see this!it will help you!<br>
[except][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160913/table-a-except-table-b-relating-more-than-one-column

Comment: The "WHERE GROUP BY" is a mistake i made when i ctrl+v ctrl+c the query.

Comment: i solved this problem with a totally different query. it's a long story. thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE '".$numbers."' NOT LIKE 'prefix%'
```

Answer (score 1):

One-query solution will look like this. Try it

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.numbers LIKE CONCAT(table2.prefix,'%') WHERE table2.prefix IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it works in a strange way. I can see even numbers matching prefixes. For example i can see: "349000000" even if in my table2.prefix there's "349". My table1.numbers is something like "whatever:3495541496@blabla" so maybe i should use **LIKE CONCAT(table2.prefix,':%@')** but it's all the same.

Comment: Please, update your post with some exact samples of your data in column `numbers`. I'll be able to fix my query